# iptables recent --mask not working

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, iptables, firewall

when I add following rule to `iptables`, everything works as expected. The offending IP is added to `BLACKLIST` and dropped.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --rsource --name BLACKLIST --update -j DROP
```

when I list my `iptables` rules with `iptables-save`, I see that automatically a netmask 255.255.255.255 is used for matching:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m recent --update --name BLACKLIST --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j DROP
```

but when I explicitly specify other mask in my rules, while I see the changed mask in `iptables-save`, it does not have the desired effect of blocking whole subnet:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m recent --update --name BLACKLIST --mask 255.255.0.0 --rsource -j DROP
```

but I see individual IPs getting through:

```
128.90.177.13
128.90.177.136
128.90.177.35
```

and individually being added to my BLACKLIST.

if mask worked, then first IP 128.90.177.13 would be added to BLACKLIST, and the other IPs from the same subnet would be blocked. But this is not what happens. They get through my rule.

Why is iptables recent --mask not working ?

I am using iptables module in kernel 4.14.274

## so, to sum up:

**I want to add offending IP to my BLACKLIST, and block whole subnet of this IP, based on netmask.**

Comment: A `-m recent --update` rule by itself doesn't do anything (you need a `--set` action somewhere). Can you show us a minimal set of firewall rules that will reproduce this problem?

Comment: @larsks - from iptables help: `--update - Match if source address in list, also update last-seen time`. Assume `128.90.177.13` is in the list. lock whole subnet `128.90.177.0/24`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to figure out what's going on in your environment without seeing a complete netfilter configuration. However, we can try putting together a simple one here and see how it behaves.

Let's start with an empty netfilter ruleset and add the following rules:

```
iptables -N bl_add
iptables -A bl_add -j LOG --log-prefix "BL_ADD "
iptables -A bl_add -j DROP
iptables -N bl_update
iptables -A bl_update -j LOG --log-prefix "BL_UPDATE "
iptables -A bl_update -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name BLACKLIST --update --mask 255.255.0.0 --seconds 20 -j bl_update
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m recent --name BLACKLIST -i eth0 --set -j bl_add
```

Here we have a couple of log/drop chains that we can use to figure out exactly where our packets are going. The `-i lo` rule isn't critical; that's just to prevent me from shooting myself in the foot.

In the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html), we see the following documentation for `--update`:

```
       [!] --rcheck
              Check if the source address of the packet is currently in
              the list.

       [!] --update
              Like --rcheck, except it will update the "last seen"
              timestamp if it matches.
```

So the `--update` options means "check (i.e. match) if the address is in the list, and if it is, update the 'last seen' timestamp". We can see the behavior in action in this example.

If I attempt to connect to port 80 on this host from 192.168.122.1, we see in the logs (`journalctl -kfl`):

```
[ 4152.729894] BL_ADD IN=eth0 OUT=
MAC=52:54:00:01:89:30:52:54:00:5d:a7:ff:08:00 SRC=192.168.122.1
DST=192.168.122.51 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22836 DF PROTO=TCP
SPT=41698 DPT=80 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
[ 4153.775211] BL_UPDATE IN=eth0 OUT=
MAC=52:54:00:01:89:30:52:54:00:5d:a7:ff:08:00 SRC=192.168.122.1
DST=192.168.122.51 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=22837 DF PROTO=TCP
SPT=41698 DPT=80 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

The first packet skips the `--update` rule -- because it isn't in the blacklist yet -- and then hits the `--set` rule, so we see the `BL_ADD` log output. The following packets stop at the `--update` rule, because now they're in the blacklist, so we see the `BL_UPDATE` log output.

With this configuration, a connection from 192.168.122.1 results in an entry like this in `/proc/net/xt_recent/BLACKLIST`:

```
src=192.168.0.0 ttl: 64 last_seen: 4303109595 oldest_pkt: 13 4303017951, 4303018971, 4303035387, 4303035595, 4303035803, 4303036211, 4303037019, 4303038685, 4303041947, 4303048411, 4303061723, 4303108569, 4303109595
```

Note that the `src` address is 192.168.0.0; our `--mask` argument was applied to transform the original `192.168.122.1` source address.

---

If we **remove** the `--set` rule, so that we have instead:

```
iptables -N bl_add
iptables -A bl_add -j LOG --log-prefix "BL_ADD "
iptables -A bl_add -j DROP
iptables -N bl_update
iptables -A bl_update -j LOG --log-prefix "BL_UPDATE "
iptables -A bl_update -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name BLACKLIST --update --mask 255.255.0.0 --seconds 20 -j bl_update
```

A connection to port 80 from 192.168.122.1 results in no log output, and no entries in `/proc/net/xt_recent/BLACKLIST`. The `--update` rule **does nothing** if the source address hasn't previously been added to `BLACKLIST` with a `--set` rule.

---

In case it's useful, the `iptables-save` output for the *working* configuration is:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [31:2152]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [16:1520]
:bl_add - [0:0]
:bl_update - [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m recent --update --seconds 20 --name BLACKLIST --mask 255.255.0.0 --rsource -j bl_update
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m recent --set --name BLACKLIST --mask 255.255.255.255 --rsource -j bl_add
-A bl_add -j LOG --log-prefix "BL_ADD "
-A bl_add -j DROP
-A bl_update -j LOG --log-prefix "BL_UPDATE "
-A bl_update -j DROP
COMMIT
```